# Storing and retrieving a custom object from NSPasteBoard

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspasteboard

I have an object that belongs to this class that contains the following declarations:

**HEADER**

```
@interface MyClassObject : NSObject <NSCopying, NSPasteboardWriting, NSPasteboardReading>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *children;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id node;
```

`children` holds other objects of this class, `node` holds objects that can be `NSView` or `NSImageView`.

I would like to be able to copy and paste objects of this type to/from `NSPasteboard`.

I have google around but the explanations are vague.

What should I do to make this class copiable/readable to NSPasteboard or in other words, make it conform to `NSPasteboardWriting` and `NSPasteboardReading` protocols?

I don't have the slightest clue on how this is done and as usual, Apple documetation and nothing is the same thing.

Comment: compare: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243668/nspasteboard-and-simple-custom-data?rq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the complete solution.

First thing is to make the class conforming to `NSCoding` too. In that case the class declaration will be

```
@interface MyClassObject : NSObject <NSCopying, NSPasteboardWriting, NSPasteboardReading, NSCoding>
```

To make it compatible with `NSCoding` you have to implement `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:`... in my case:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

  [coder encodeObject:@(self.type) forKey:@"type"];
  [coder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
  // converting the node to NSData... 
  // the object contained in node must be compatible with NSCoding
  NSData *nodeData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.node];
  [coder encodeObject:nodeData forKey:@"node"];

  NSData *childrenData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.children];
  [coder encodeObject:childrenData forKey:@"children"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

  self = [super init];

  if (self) {

    _type = [[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"type"] integerValue];
    _name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];

    NSData *nodeData = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"node"];
    _efeito = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:nodeData];

    NSData *childrenData = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"children"];
    _children = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:childrenData];
    _parent = nil;  // I want this to be nil when the object is recreated
  }
```

To make the class work with NSPasteboard you have to add these 4 methods:

```
-(id)initWithPasteboardPropertyList:(id)propertyList ofType:(NSString *)type {
  return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:propertyList];
}


+(NSArray *)readableTypesForPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard {
    // I am using the bundleID as a type  
    return @[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
}

- (NSArray *)writableTypesForPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard {
  // I am using the bundleID as a type  
  return @[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
}


- (id)pasteboardPropertyListForType:(NSString *)type {
  // I am using the bundleID as a type  
  if(![type isEqualToString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]]) {
    return nil;
  }

  return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
}
```

Then, on the class you implement the copy and paste you add:

```
- (void)copy:(id)sender {

  NSPasteboard *pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
  [pasteBoard clearContents];

  NSArray *copiedObjects = @[theObjectYouWantToCopyToThePasteboard];
  [pasteBoard writeObjects:copiedObjects];

}

- (void)paste:sender {

  NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
  NSArray *classArray = @[[LayerObject class]];
  NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];

  BOOL ok = [pasteboard canReadItemWithDataConformingToTypes:@[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]]];

  if (ok) {
    NSArray *objectsToPaste = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:classArray options:options];
    MyObjectClass *object = [objectsToPaste objectAtIndex:0];

    // object is the one you have copied to the pasteboard
    // now you can do whatever you want with it.
    // add the code here.    
  }
}
```

Comment: This was a big help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ill only discuss writing. it is basically the same for reading (but in reverse of course ;))

## write

1. declare the type you write

   ```
   - (NSArray *)writableTypesForPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard {
       return @[@"com.mycompany.mytype"];
   }
   ```
2. write the data

   ```
   - (id)pasteboardPropertyListForType:(NSString *)type {
       //check the type we are asked to write
       if(![type isEqualToString:@"com.mycompany.mytype"]) return nil;    

       //create a _plist_ object
       // :: ONLY PLIST TYPES
       NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

       ...

       return plist;
   }
   ```

Comment: create a plist object? never did that... is that ask too much for you to include the code to do that? 

Comment: only stuff that can go to userDefaults can go there -- which means everything must be encodable... you can use a NSCoder.

Comment: it is easy enough except for children and parent

Comment: actually plist is more restricted than any object that implements NSCoding. It's something like only numbers, strings, data, and a few other types

Comment: Of course you could serialize any non-plist classes that support *NSCoding* as *NSData*

Comment: @nielsbot you guys are discussing the theory behind that. Theory that I don't know. It would be a great achievement for the man kind if you guys post code. thanks.

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper no too much effort. Check tutorials from apply on serialising an object graph

Comment: be back in a year when I underestant that. Thanks.